# What is the cause of my resistor going up in flames?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, repair

An LED strip in my kitchen recently died, and from looking at damage to the circuit board, I figured the cause was either a resistor, a capacitor, or both. Images:

Resistor damage ([full size left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYPT5.jpg), [full size right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFJ0m.jpg)):

[image]
[image]

Capacitor damage ([full size left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhSoQ.jpg), [full size right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qro9x.jpg)):

[image]
[image]

Since, apparently, my house was impossible to find for the parcel deliveryman carrying the replacement capacitor, despite literally every other delivery person ever finding it, I figured I'd just try replacing the resistor (which had arrived on time) and see if that would fix the problem.

Unfortunately, it failed spectacularly instead, with the replacement resistor going up in flames. I don't think that did any non-visual damage to the board, but since I'm not too experienced with electronics, I am curious about what the cause of the resistor combustion was. See here for the aftermath of the flame (with the dead replacement resistor already removed again and placed beside the board)

[image]

My working theory is that the resistor was never the problem, only the symptom, and the capacitor (or perhaps something else entirely) is the real problem. In other words, the original resistor only died because the capacitor died first, and replacing the resistor simply caused the replacement's death as well because the capacitor was still broken. Is this a plausible explanation?

Alternatively, it may be possible that I picked the wrong resistor. I read the original resistor as a 1kΩ 10% tolerance resistor with unknown wattage, and thus replaced it with a 1kΩ 1% tolerance 1/2W resistor. Did I interpret the colors on the original resistor correctly? Or is perhaps the wattage of the replacement too low?

Since I'm sort of an amateur concerning electronics repair, I'm not sure what could be the causes of a) my lamp dying and b) the resistor going up in flames. Can anyone answer these questions for me?

---

Addendum: more photos in response to comments / answers:

- [entire circuit board (back)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdG0f.jpg)
- [entire circuit board (front)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DFw0.jpg)
- [IC close-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzoEU.jpg)
- [IC super-close-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmFSC.jpg)

---

---

*Follow-up: after replacing the IC, condensator and inductor, the lamp worked again :D*

Comment: It’s rather difficult to say without a schematic, and it’s tricky to derive one from those photos.

Comment: Looks like an inductor to me. Does the pcb say L1 or suchlike? From what I can see, putting a 1K resistor in that position is not advisable. I would suggest the LNK364 chip has failed due to the electrolytic capacitor drying up.

Comment: @Kartman having not been aware that inductors look rather similar to resistors, I foolishly thought what I was looking at was the former. Now that you mention it, it does make more sense (visually) for this to be an inductor

Comment: @Frog I added more photos to my question that show the entire board :)

Comment: As Howie says, the ic has let out the magic smoke. I’d suggest checking the resistors and diodes. The main electro has failed as that usually causes the ic to die. As for the inductor - just replace it with a bit of wire. Or simply buy a new board - most likely an easier and cheaper solution.

Comment: @Kartman the point of this repair is not money, buying a new board or entire lamp would already have been cheaper, considering the cost of a soldering iron and the replacement parts. The point is repairing instead of just throwing it out, and learning something in the process.

Comment: Probably unrelated: On your photo of the "entire circuit board (back)", I notice a suspicious solder blob shorting out two neighbor pins of the 4 diodes.

Comment: @akwky not quite unrelated, but irrelevant for this problem. That's just a loose solder blob that dropped there, it's from unsoldering the burnt-out resistor. To ensure we're talking about the same thing, right below that blob should be one of the holes where the resistor was soldered.

Comment: Size matters.  The initial resistor is larger than the replacement resistor.  That means it can dissipate more power.  It burned up.  The replacement burned up.  So the resistor is dissipating more power than it initially did.  You can replace it with a higher wattage resistor, but why did the initial resistor die.  Odds are that something else failed.

Comment: 100% that's an inductor.  No question about it.   Your one photo even shows the guts. 
 Look up "RF chokes" if you wanna try to replace it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the small dark spot on the capacitor, it is the IC that has expelled smoke towards it and left a mark on it. The capacitor is very likely OK as it doesn't have the characteristic signs of failure, such as either top or bottom being bent outwards from pressure, although it can be bad without visual clues.

The part which has failed is an inductor, chances are it's marked BROWN-BLACK-BROWN, which is 1-0-1, or 100 micro-Henries, but it may have looked red and you thought it was 1000 (ohms, because you assumed it was a resistor).

The reason your replacement resistor failed is because its resistance is too large and power too small to withstand the momentary current and power through it at the moment of turn on, AND because the IC has likely failed SHORT so you have a short circuit across the input capacitor.
Normally, a 10 ohm WIREWOUND resistor of AT LEAST 1W power rating is used at the input of a small power supply like yours, to reduce the inrush current at the moment of powering it on and protect the input components.
The inductor serves similar purpose, plus it reduces the switching IC interference being fed back into the power line.

If I were you, I would replace the IC (I would possibly use an equivalent one with a higher power rating so that it is less likely to fail again), the inductor with another one or with a 10 ohm, 1W wirewound resistor, and I would check all components at the input up to the IC, as some input diodes may have burnt as well.

The ORIGINAL reason why your supply has failed could be a surge on the power line, a failed LED (or LEDs), or the insufficient power rating of the IC. Below are the power ratings from its manual:
[image]

What is the power rating of your LED light?

Comment: I don't know the power rating of the LEDs, it doesn't say (or I don't know where to look). There's a "BART-L36-230V-K1" label on the led strip, but since there are 36 leds on the strip and I'm on european 230V power, I don't think that's going to be of any help. If it's relevant, the light died when I had guests over and one of them switched on the lamp; it didn't suddenly die while already running.

Comment: If you could give me a sharp picture of the output (after the transformer), I might be able to figure out the output voltage and current, and thus the power. Is there any other label on the whole unit from the outside?

Comment: I assume the transformer is the big yellow-black component with copper tape across it (correct me if I'm wrong). However, I'm not sure what you mean by "output", or what exactly I should photograph. There is unfortunately no label on the outside (or inside) of the plastic shell, it's just a nondescript housing that can probably fit several different variants of this lamp.

Comment: Yes, that's the transformer, and the output side goes from it to the wires connected to LEDs.

Comment: update: replacing IC, condensator (now that the parcel delivery man finally managed to find my house on the second try, ugh) and inductor fixed the problem :) Some of the LEDs are quite dim, so perhaps that increased the load on the electrical components and ultimately caused the failure, but for now, the lamp is working again :D

Comment: Glad you fixed it. The dim LEDs could either increase or decrease the load, it depends on their failure mode, whether they develop a short or an increased resistance (an open). If some of them develop a short, it reduces the output voltage which can lead most LED drivers to shut off or cycle on and off as they have a range of output voltages which they try to maintain. If a single LED in series has an increased resistance or is open, that would lead to an overvoltage at the output, shutting the driver off or burning it by causing a high voltage across the input components due to no load.

Answer (score 1):

The photos look to me like the burnt marking on the capacitor has come from the side of the IC.  Heat inside the IC probably cause the case to crack on the side and a flame came out and burnt the capacitor label.

It is likely that the IC has broken which has then cause the resistor to burn out.

Whether there is something else wrong that has caused the IC to break could only be determined by doing more diagnostics.

Comment: I added more images to my question showing the entire circuit board (I unfortunately don't have a proper schematic) and a close-up of the IC. It looks rather undamaged to me, to be honest.

Comment: Your new photos still suggest the IC has failed.

Comment: Look at the gap between 2 pins on the IC, the image is not detailed enough, but it looks like a small hole through which it blew out. You can use your phone's zoom to see the detail.

Comment: @EdinFifić I added another picture to my question. You're right, it could be the point of failure. I just wasn't aware that the IC wasn't supposed to look like that ^^

Comment: It's DEFINITELY the point of failure or the hole through which the "magic smoke" has escaped or blew out.

Comment: update: replacing IC, condensator (now that the parcel delivery man finally managed to find my house on the second try, ugh) and inductor fixed the problem :) Some of the LEDs are quite dim, so perhaps that increased the load on the electrical components and ultimately caused the failure, but for now, the lamp is working again :D

Answer (score 0):

Given where the resistor is on the board, it's not only acting as a resistor for current inrush limiting, but it's acting as a fuse as well.

Something else has shorted out on the board, and instantly blowing the fusible resistor.

Comment: The reddish/brownish square component at the input is the fuse, the INDUCTOR (not a resistor) is acting merely as an inrush current limiter, though it can also serve as a fuse, but that's not its purpose here.